# How to connect with two database instances?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Unable to get results from many to one relation
 I have two database:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "admin")
    public void setAdminEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "user")
    public void setUserEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

----------------------------------------------

@Entity
@Table(name = "cd_state")
@NamedQueries({ 
    @NamedQuery(name = "State.findAll", query = "Select s from State s order by s.stateName ASC "),  

})
public class State {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long stateId;
    private String stateCode;
    private String stateName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "countryId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Country country;
    private Boolean isActive;
    private Long countryId;
getters and setters//
}

country belongs to admin databases::
-----------------------------

public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        TypedQuery<User> query = getuserEntityManager().createNamedQuery(FIND_ALL_USERS, User.class);

        List<User> list = query.getResultList();

        return list;
    }

it throws exception.not connecting to admin database.
```

Comment: I don't see any question mark.

Comment: we have two databases.many to one relation is not getting results.how to connect with another database implicitly

Comment: @user3386628 Please edit your question/post, rather than writing comments.

Comment: Check you admin DB configurations ? What exceptions does it throws ?

Answer (score 0):

Create two @PersistenceContext which has 2 different database configurations.

Answer (score 0):

This answer I provided to a previous question provides code examples demonstrating how to do it:

[Multiple jpa:repositories in xml config, how to configure with @EnableJPARepositories using Spring java config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008809/multiple-jparepositories-in-xml-config-how-to-configure-with-enablejpareposit/19976132#19976132)