# Spring fails to choose between multiple TransactionManager beans

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I migrating my spring batch processes from a command line application to a spring boot webapp including the spring-batch-admin-manager (version 1.3.0).

My old command-line app worked with two JPA databases and two `TransactionManager` instances. I remember it has been a hell of configuration to get that running. I expected things to get more comfortable, when starting with Spring Boot, but now things seem to be even worse:

**Spring is unable to choose the right TransactionManager instance for transactions.**

On application startup Spring is visiting one of my classes to execute a `@PostConstruct` annotated code block, from where a transactional method should be called.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
  eventType = eventTypeBo.findByLabel("Sport"); // <-- Calling transactional method
  //...
}
```

From here the error is thrown. Have a look at the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: 
           No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined: 
           expected single matching bean but found 2: transactionManager,osm.transactionManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:313)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:337)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:252)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.findByLabel(Unknown Source)
    at com.company.model.service.impl.EventTypeBo.findByLabel(EventTypeBo.java:43)
    at com.company.batch.article.utils.converter.SomeConverter.init(SomeConverter.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    //...
```

As you can see from the error log my `TransactionManager`s are named "transactionManager" and "osm.transactionManager". Transactions are configured accordingly:

```
<!-- DATABASE 1 -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- DATABASE 2 -->
<bean id="osm.transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="osm.entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="osm.transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="osmServiceOperation"
        expression="execution(* com.qompa.osm.service.spec..*Service.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="osmServiceOperation" />
</aop:config>
```

I am using two different GenericDao implementions to distinguish between `PersistenceContext`s when accessing data:

```
public class OsmGenericDao<T> implements IGenericDao<T> {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "osm.entityManagerFactory")
  protected EntityManager em;
  //...
}

public class GenericDao<T> implements IGenericDao<T> {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "entityManagerFactory")
  protected EntityManager em;
  //...
}
```

Everything seems to be fproperly configured: But still it fails!

**EDIT:** As far as I can follow Spring's `TransactionAspectSuppor`t tries to determine the transactionmanager via a qualifier (determineTransactionManager). Because the findByLabel's `@Transactional` annotation has no qualifier it tries to determine the correct bean with help of `DefaultListableBeanFactory`"s getBean method, where two beans of the same type are found that can't be further distinguished.

**There must be a way to tell Spring to choose the transactionManager according to the persistence context!**

Any ideas?

Comment: Ditch the `<tx:adivce />` and `<aop:config />` and remove `transaction-manager="transactionManager"` from `<tx:annotation-driven />`. Instead use `@Transactional` everywhere and specify which transaction manager to use on it those `@Transactional` beans.

Comment: I found that an ugly solution, because i tie my modules to a specific TransactionManager name. It has been working before, so it should now ... there must be another way!

Comment: So you don't mind binding it to a specific entitymanager but a tx manazger is a problem?. With `@Transactional` you need to specify which to use, in case of multiple managers. If you don't use multiple `<tx:advice />` bllocks.

Comment: Maybe I am a bit picky ... I will try it out! Still it looks ugly to me to add a name to every single @Transactional annotation in the codebase (which means refactoring nearly one hundred classes)

Comment: It's ugly indeed. I think you must have something wrong in your configuration because I remember working with two separate persistence contexts without a problem. I'll try to find it and come back with an answer.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008809/multiple-jparepositories-in-xml-config-how-to-configure-with-enablejpareposit/19976132#19976132

Comment: @M.Deinum I finally chose your solution. If you post an answer I am going to accept it!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my working configuration with 2 persistence contexts:

```
<!-- METADATA -->

<!-- Metadata connection pool -->
<bean id="scprMetadataDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass"
        value="..." />
    <property name="jdbcUrl"
        value="..." />
    <property name="user"
        value="..." />
    <property name="password"
        value="..." />
    <property name="maxPoolSize"
        value="..." />
    <property name="minPoolSize"
        value="..." />
</bean>

<!-- Metadata entity manager factory -->
<bean id="scprMetadataEntityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="H2" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Metadata transaction manager -->
<bean id="scprMetadataTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="scprMetadataEntityManagerFactory" />
</bean>


<!-- DOMAIN -->

<!-- Domain connection pool -->
<bean id="scprDomainDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass"
        value="..." />
    <property name="jdbcUrl"
        value="..." />
    <property name="user"
        value="..." />
    <property name="password"
        value="..." />
    <property name="maxPoolSize"
        value="..." />
    <property name="minPoolSize"
        value="..." />
</bean>

<!-- Domain entity manager factory -->
<bean id="scprDomainEntityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="SQL_SERVER" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Domain transaction manager -->
<bean id="scprDomainTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="scprDomainEntityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

Other config (missing in your question):

```
<persistence-unit name="scpr_metadata" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <class>...</class>
    <class>...</class>
    <class>...</class>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="scpr_domain" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <class>...</class>
    <class>...</class>
    <class>...</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

And in my java class:

```
@Repository
public final class MetadataRepositoryImpl implements MetadataRepository {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "scpr_metadata")
private EntityManager em;
```

And:

```
@Repository
public final class DomainRepositoryImpl implements DomainRepository {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "scpr_domain")
private EntityManager em;
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been doing. Just ommitted the persistence.xml in my question. The same configuration i am having now is up and running in a command line app. That's why I think it might be a spring boot config issue ... Thank you anyway!